# Can vs can't of street photography in New Zealand

Tags: legal, street-photography

Let's say a photographer takes some street photography and **sells** the prints in a gallery.

What is ok vs not ok regarding people being in the photos, that are taken in NZ?

Let's assume the photographer is not being a d* ck and if someone asks them to not photograph them, they don't, they don't misrepresent a subject etc etc
Let's also assume the photos are not for journalism.

What would make the following ok:

1. Crowd of people in a public place  (e.g., crossing the street)
2. A single person in a public place  (e.g., crossing the street)
3. Crowd of people in a public-private place (e.g., bar or cafe)
4. Single person in a public-private place (e.g., bar or cafe)
5. Crowd of people on private property which is not open to the public.
6. Single person on private property which is not open to the public

Would permission be needed, would it need to be in writing etc etc? Would it make a difference if the photograph was used to advertise the opening of the show at the gallery?

*(I know these are several questions, but it would be silly to split them into several which would then be flagged as duplicates!)*
.

Comment: You might also ask if there are limitations w.r.t. what you may do with an image.  e.g. here in the us you can photograph subjects in public (even without consent) but you cannot use those images for commercial purposes without consent.

Comment: @TimCampbell Isn't that clear from the first sentence?

Comment: @DarcyThomas Here in the U.S., selling prints, in and of itself, is not considered "commercial usage", which is defined as use that implies or states that the subject is endorsing a product or service. "Editorial" usage is not considered "commercial", even if one must pay to see it in a newspaper, magazine, or online site. "Artistic" usage is not considered "commercial" if the purpose of the work is artistic, rather than to sell something, etc.

Comment: ... "Something" that is other than the artwork itself.

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, your **buyer** might not want to purchase shots of identifiable people without a model release (if they use such a shot in e.g. commercial company promo material, _they_ might get in legal trouble, not you). Thus, even if you take a candid street shot, if a shot is really good it could be worth asking them to sign a model release.

Comment: I find there is a fair amount of (culture-independent) non-verbal interaction that can help with street shots. A smile and a nod could go a long way in making the person not feel exposed, though it all depends on context.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff Out of scope of this question. But valuable advise all the same. I shoot with film so don't have a chance to check if it is a great shot in the moment. However if I ever feel that what I have captured has the potential then I will see about getting a release or contact details of the subject. Thanks 

Answer (score 8):

Ask the New Zealand Police...

https://www.police.govt.nz/faq/what-are-rules-around-taking-photos-or-filming-public-place

> It is generally lawful to take photographs of people in public places without their consent. However, you must not film or take photos of people if they are in a place where they can expect privacy (such as a public changing area or toilet) and that person:
>
> - is naked, in underclothes, showering, toileting etc
> - is unaware of being filmed or photographed
> - has not given consent to be filmed or photographed.
>
> You should not take photos of people if:
>
> - they are in a place where they would expect reasonable privacy and publication would be highly offensive to an objective and reasonable person
> - it has potential to stop other people's use and enjoyment of the same place
> - you have no legitimate reason for taking the film or photos.
>
> However, you can take and/or publish photos or film of people where there is no expectation of privacy, such as a beach, shopping mall, park or other public place.

Comment: FYI Link only answers are not the best because the link can go bad.  It is better to explicitly say what is in the link as well as reference the link

Comment: @PeterM; I updated the post... that should be adequate I think.

Comment: Well… except that pictures are not text-searchable. I also think that's just a tad vague & doesn't include potential commercial applications.

Comment: @Tetsujin, "publish" is commercial usage. I just had a look at the copyright/privacy laws and it appears that they are very similar to EU/UK laws in regard to using a person's likeness commercially (i.e. model releases are not typically required).

Comment: What is a "public place" though? Sometimes "a place the public has access to". But the owner of a shopping mall can restrict any activity on their property. And (unlike e.g. the UK) pretty much anywhere in NZ has an owner (councils, DOC, NZTA). Beaches may be the only exception?

Comment: @Rich, a public space is any space the public has unrestricted access to (i.e. free, not ticketed/restricted). In any country I can think of all property/land has an owner/controller that can impose limitations, even if it is the government/crown and not a private entity.

Comment: *Publish* does not equal *commercial* in most countries. Posting a photo to instagram or facebook is considered "publishing" by the copyright laws or any country, including NZ, that belong to the Berne Convention. Even when money is exchanged for access to or for a copy of an image, such as the paid admission to an art gallery or the cost of a newspaper containing photos as editorial content, that's not considered "commercial" usage of a photograph. Any monetary activity associated with a photograph does not make the usage of a given photograph *commercial*.

Comment: Even if there is no cost to see a photo and the photographer did not get paid for providing an image, such as a billboard, if the likeness of a person in a image implies that they endorse a service or product, then that is commercial usage.

Comment: @MichaelC, US copyright law: "What is publication?
Publication has a technical meaning in copyright law. According to the statute, “Publication is the distribution of copies or phonorecords of a work to the public by sale or other transfer of ownership, or by rental, lease, or lending." https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq-definitions.html

Comment: UK copyright law: "(4)The following do not constitute publication for the purposes of this Part and references to commercial publication shall be construed accordingly—(a)in the case of a literary, dramatic or musical work—(i)the performance of the work, or (ii)the [F1communication to the public of the work] (otherwise than for the purposes of an electronic retrieval system);" 175 Meaning of publication and commercial publication. (1)In this Part “publication”, in relation to a work— (a)means the issue of copies to the public, https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/48/section/175

Comment: It seems to me they were very clear/careful to use "publication" (public performance/making public) and "publish" (distribute copies) separately and appropriately IMO.

Comment: Digital copies are still copies. No physical media must be distributed. The sections of statutes you quote were written years ago. The DMCA and more recent court decisions have made clear that those statutes also apply to digitally distributed/published content.

Comment: notes
1. This circular is intended as an overview of the basic concepts of copyright. The authoritative
source for U.S. copyright law is the Copyright Act, codified in Title 17 of the United States Code. Copyright Office regulations are codified in Title 37 of the Code of Federal Regulations. Copyright Office
practices and procedures are summarized in the third edition of the Compendium of U.S. Copyright
Office Practices, cited as the Compendium. The copyright law, regulations, and the Compendium are
available on the Copyright Office website at www.copyright.gov.

Comment: "Under copyright law, publication is the distribution of copies or phonorecords of a work to the
public by sale or other transfer of ownership or by rental, lease, or lending. Offering to distribute
copies or phonorecords to a group of people for purposes of further distribution, public performance, or public display also constitutes publication." (https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ01.pdf#page=7)

Comment: @MichaelC; Yes, digital copies are still copies. But digital display does not necessarily equate to digital distribution. It is the difference between me putting an image on my website/portfolio w/ all rights reserved; utilizing my exclusive right to display and make copies. Vs putting it online with a creative commons license allowing downloads; transferring the right to make copies, distributing the file/image, and transferring legal ownership/possession. What someone else does illegally/outside of my control is not my problem.

Comment: That's why the UK law specifically separates digital display from an "electronic retrieval system" (i.e. file sharing/distribution)... the US law leaves it a little more vague. But as you said; all signatories to the Berne Convention have the same basic intent/purpose/meanings.

Comment: In the U.S. posting an image that the "general public" can access and view is considered publishing, even if it is posted with all rights reserved and "downloading" features are disabled. Books all have "copyright" and "rights reserved" language in the front. Purchasing or possessing a copy of the book does not give one intellectual property rights to the contents. Granting of IP rights is not required to qualify an online image as "publishing". I'm not familiar enough with UK law to argue your assertion that such is not the case there, but if you are correct that's rather surprising to me.

Comment: @MichaelC; From the copyright office definitions FAQ: "What is publication?
Publication has a technical meaning in copyright law. According to the statute, ... *A public performance or display of a work does not of itself constitute publication.” Generally, publication occurs on the date on which copies of the work are first made available to the public.*"  https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-definitions.html But you cannot distribute copies (publish) w/o also making the information known (publication), so the terms intertwine. The distinction is between transferring possession and display

Comment: But copyright law is not privacy law; which is where commercial use concerns arise. In the U.S. commercial use is using someone's likeness for profit (i.e selling published copies). And in other countries, as well as the U.S., it is also using someone's likeness to advocate a product or idea (called "passing off" in UK/EU law which is what NZ law appears to follow https://www.inbrief.co.uk/human-rights/image-rights/).

Comment: @StevenKersting Again, possession of a digital copy of an image is still *possession*, and thus entails *distribution*, and thus is *publishing*. Ownership of the IP in the digital image, or of usage rights, is not required to establish *possession*. If you download an image, you possess that image, even if you do not own the IP rights or a usage license to it. If an image is posted on an internet page that is generally accessible to the public, or even only accessible to a group of paid subscribers that is open to anyone willing to pay the subscription fee, it is considered *published*.

Comment: @MichaelC; No, legal/authorized possession of a copy is distribution/publishing. If you download an image (screen capture, etc) when not authorized it is not legal possession and it falls outside of the regulations. Publication (making known to the public) is separate from publishing (distributing copies)... If what you say is accurate, I could not use any image of any individual for any purpose w/o a release/waiver; and that is simply not true.

Comment: @StevenKersting If I upload an image to my website and allow downloading (without resorting to "workarounds" such as screenshots that violate things such as the DMCA), say via a "download" button coded into the page, and I give explicit or implicit permission to download for personal use, I'm publishing, not displaying. If I allow people to download the images I post on Flickr using the "download" functions built into that page with explicit licensing, I'm publishing, not displaying.

Comment: If I have a "for pay" section of my website to which anyone with a paypal account can subscribe and I provide images for download with an explicit single copy only, personal use only license, I am publishing because I am distributing *legal* copies of the image. If I post images to most social media platforms, which include user agreements that state any content uploaded includes permission for the use of that content by the owners of the platform that may or may not be limited to providing the images on the platform, I'm distributing legal copies (to the platform's servers) and publishing.

Comment: @MichaelC, No argument there... if you distribute legal copies by whatever means it equals publishing. Exposing the images through any of those means with  *all rights reserved* is simply display of the image and not an issue unless it violates a separate personal/privacy right.